# underscore _.filter condition

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Is it possible to do something like this using underscore _.filter?

```
self.getCols = function (columnId) {
return cols = _.filter(self.model.cols(), function(c) {
    return (
            (c.Id === self.model.Id()) &&
            ((columnId === undefined) ? '' : c.columnId === columnId)           
    );
});
```

};

right now the condition I'm using on columnId is not valid. Sorry my bad, I just edited in a proper way.

Comment: Could you supply a bit more context about what you are trying to achieve with the column ID filtering.  Also the context of `self.model`?

Comment: I want all columns from self.model.cols() if columnId is undefined, otherwise brings only the one I specified

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: What should happen if c.Id !== self.model.Id() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case your return should be (I think):

```
return c.columnID || c.Id === self.model.ID();
```

Thats assuming that 'columns you specify' is interpreted as a column with `Id` property equal to `self.model.ID()`

Answer (score 0):

`filter` doesn't really care what you do in the callback as long as you return either a truthy (which includes the current item), or falsy (excludes the current item).

As for the expression, it's true only when:

- `c.Id === self.model.Id()`
- `columnId` exists
- `columndId` is equal to `c.columnId`.

And so we write it that way:

```
c.Id === self.model.Id() && columnId && c.columnId === columnId
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what to do with `self.model.Id()`, but I think that this is something along the line of what you describe (including the comment):

```
self.getCols = function getCols (columnId) {
    var cols = self.model.cols();

    if (columnId === undefined) {
        return cols;
    }

    return _.filter(cols, function (c) {
        return c.columnId === columnId;
    });
}
```